# BreezeSharp client and the TimeSpan issue

Tags: breeze, timespan, breeze-sharp

We're unable to re-hydrate the Breeze# client object which has TimeSpan? properties and if prop value is not null

BreezeServer returns the TimeSpan in the ISO 8601 format (eq. "PT8H") but as [TimeSpan.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx)  expects different format *[ws][-]{ d | [d.]hh:mm[:ss[.ff]] }[ws]* a System.FormatException is thrown ("String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan") in the Breeze.Sharp.JsonEntityConverter while parsing objects.

Is this a known issue? IS there any workaround for it?

Comment: I'll look it it later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this was a bug and has been fixed in the lastest version on the **breeze.sharp** GitHub repo, it will also go out in the next release, probably sometime next week. Please confirm whether or not it corrects your issue.

Comment: The issue is now fixed. Thanks @JayTraband for a quick turnaround. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Jay, any info on when will the version 0.6.0.3 be available on Nugget? I see it's referenced in DocCode.

Comment: Probably within the next few days.